# Store for loop queryset into one

Tags: python, django

I currently have an array with multiple objects. The for loop does a queryset based upon the array objects using a for loop of a model.

```
search_post = ["1990", "2023"]
for query in search_post:
    vehicle_result = Vehicle.objects.filter(
        Q(title__icontains=query) |
        Q(details__icontains=query) |
        Q(year__icontains=query) |
        Q(notes__icontains=query)
    )
    print('vehicle_result: %s' % vehicle_result)
```

The issue I'm having is when the array has multiple items it's going through the for loop for each object and it's outputting each objects result. Only the last object result is retained if I call this variable elsewhere in the code.

Example Output:

```
vehicle_result: <QuerySet [<Vehicle: BMW>]>
vehicle_result: <QuerySet [<Vehicle: Toyota>, <Vehicle: Mercedes>, <Vehicle: Honda>]>
```

I want to store/combine them all into one variable - prevent losing all the results (right now only the last one is retained I guess because the variable is overwritten)

How can I achieve?

Comment: there are undefined variables in the example code.
the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: what is `Vehicle` ? it is not defined...

Comment: @D.L `Vehicle` is a django model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to build up your query, then filter on it so that the queryset doesn't change on each iteration.

```
q = Q()

for query in search_posts:
    q |= Q(title__icontains = query)
    q |= Q(details__icontains = query)
    q |= Q(year__icontains = query)
    q |= Q(notes__icontains = query)

Vehicle.objects.filter(q)
```

This will add a `Q` object with an OR for each field, with each search_post item.
There's neater ways, but best not to overcomplicate things early.

Comment: Thank you - This solved it. So simple and elegant.

Comment: i dont know what this does but it certainly looks elegant.

Answer (score 1):

We can simplify this by constructing a single `Q` object with:

```
from django.db.models import Q

search_post = ['1990', '2023']
fields = ['title', 'details', 'year', 'notes']
fitler_q = Q(
    *[(f'{field}__icontains', val) for val in search_post for field in fields],
    _connector=Q.OR,
)
Vehicle.objects.filter(filter_q)
```